# Reusing GUID in WIX between installers for the same environment component

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm building a couple of installers for our internal PowerShell modules. We're installing all the modules into the same folder structure. I have to update the `PSModulePath` environment variable. Do I reuse the same GUID for the component between installers since its the same component or does it need to be unique per installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd author that component as shared and put it into a fragment file.   Then in your various installers use a ComponentRef to pull it into your feature.

This way the last installer uninstalled will remove that component.

Comment: This plus you're comment below cleared it up for me, thanks. Do you have link to a good example of using the ComponetRef with a shared fragment file, I tried to find one but have thus come up empty.

Comment: The link above shows steps 1 2 and 3 in one wxs files but you can easily create additional wxs fragement files and split it out.  They key to remember is when you use a ref tl an element in a fragement that everything in the element  gets processed.  If this still doesn't make sense, send me an email and I'll shoot you a sample project.

Comment: Here's another good example: http://geekswithblogs.net/Vagmi.Mudumbai/archive/2004/11/23/15669.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would go with what @Christopher suggested, but to answer your specific question, I would say that WIX wants you to continue to use to continue to use the same GUID for each specific file.

From http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/generate_guids.htm (emphasis mine):

> For the Component element the generated GUID is based on the install directory and filename of the KeyPath for the component. **This GUID will stay consistent from build-to-build provided the directory and filename of the KeyPath do not change.**

So, if a file has the same directory and filename, then WIX will continue to assign it the same GUID, which they wouldn't do if they wanted the same file to have a different GUID each installer.

Comment: KeyPaths are not always files.  Automatic GUID generation only applies to components that have file KeyPaths.   Components contain resources of various types ( folders, files, registry, ini, envrionment, ectera ) and the key is that the component is globally unique and globally compatible.    This is an example of such a component so thus I'd put it into a single component and give it a static Component ID (guid).

Comment: Here's better reference material: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370561(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sure, KeyPaths indeed are not always files, but am I mistaken in saying that version 1 and version 2 (same dir & name) of a file will continue to have the same KeyPath, and therefore the same auto-GUID for WIX? Powershell modules, which are mentioned in the question, are files, so this particular question seemed like it was specifically asking about components that happen to be files.

Comment: To me, he wasn't asking about all the other components, he was asking about the component that handles environment.  Eitherway, autoguid's are just syntactical sugar to solve the annoyance of having to create and author guids.  If you are using WiX fragments to reuse components then it's really not that big of a deal to statically generate the guid's and move on.  There's no reason to introduce the complexity of auto guids.

Comment: BTW, if you have resharper you can use the nguid snippet. It's really sweet.